# Parametrization of Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an [application](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb) that is comprised of an Angular front-end, an app layer and a DB layer. You can see the architecture in [this image](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/yelb-architecture.png).

I am using an nginx instance to serve both the JS front-end bits to the client as well as to proxy requests from the client to the app layer. So let's say I deploy this nginx on a cloud VM with IP 18.1.1.1 (fake) I can point my browser to that IP, the client will download the JS code, and the JS code is configured, see [here](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/yelb-ui/clarity-seed-newfiles/src/environments/environment.prod.ts), to set the app server ip/fqdn to the same ip/fqdn I pointed my browser to download the ui. 
At this point the nginx proxy configuration [kicks in](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/yelb-ui/startup.sh) and forward all /api requests made by the JS code to a specific fqdn. Right now this is a specific FQDN just because I am deploying these components as containers and the nginx container always knows how to reach `http://yelb-appserver:4567/api`.

I would like now to create additional deployment methods and in particular I would like to host the Angular bits on an S3 bucket (or any other web server) and have the JS point directly to something like an API GW, a separate EC2 instance, a cloud load balancer, or anything that represents an IP/FQDN endpoint different from the IP/FQDN of the web server serving the JS files. 
In this case I can no longer use the `appserver_env: 'http://' + window.location.host` that I have used [here](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/yelb-ui/clarity-seed-newfiles/src/environments/environment.prod.ts).

Since I would like to create a dynamic and repeatable deployment workflow (using cloudformation, or similar) I am wondering if there is a way to work with a single JS compiled artifact parametrizing the Angular code to point to the /api endpoint created at deployment time OR if my only option is, at every deployment, to 1) create/read the /api endpoint at deployment time, 2) programmatically customize the Angular code with the endpoint, 3) re-build the Angular app dynamically (now including the specific /api endpoint) and 4) finally deploy the web site with the JS code ad-hoc created with the custom /api endpoint for that specific application instance deployed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use environment variables and keep them in a config (like "environment.prod.ts" in your case), which will be given to a node process running your build. Your javascript angular code can use these variables, like for api endpoint, you can have `process.env.API_ENDPOINT` in you code wherever you need api endpoint. Now for supplying thses variables you can use something, as simple as, `API_ENDPOINT='/api' npm run build` or for more advanced approach, you can use Docker.

Comment: Thanks @shishir. Indeed this would be my plan B (with the usage of variable Vs the "tweaking" I was alluding to). I am still hoping for another solution that allows not to re-compile the code for every deployment but it looks like option B is what I will have to go with. Thanks.